# CSS position of link and text is massed up on certain screen size/resolution

Tags: css

I made a website using HTML and CSS. The position of all the links and info is done through CSS with the following method:

```
position: absolute;
top; Xpx;
right; Ypx;
```

It looks good on my screen, but now on different screens everything is messed up...

How can I make sure it looks as I want, on any screen size/resolution?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Pretty tough to give you a good answer without seeing an example of the problem.

Using pure absolute positioning for everything is not generally good practice these days.

You are calculating positions from the top right corner, so something that looks centered on your display will be in a different position on a larger/smaller display. And things can run off-screen on smaller displays.

If you are using position absolute within responsive elements, care should be taken as to how they are positioned and how their height/width is defined.

If I position something 10px from the left  edge of a container and make it 200px width, and the container changes size with the window size then my absolutely positioned element may end up in an unsuitable location, or sticking out of it's container. On the other hand, if I set it `left: 10%;` `width: 80%` then that would leave 10% space on the right as well, and it would scale with the container.

In general, absolute positioning should be used within elements whose behavior can be predicted and accounted for.